# How to install only "devDependencies" using npm

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json

I am trying to install ONLY the "devDependencies" listed in my package.json file. But none of the following commands work as I expect. All of the following commands install the production dependencies also which I do not want.

```
npm install --dev
npm install --only=dev
npm install --only-dev
```

I cannot think of any more ways of telling the npm to install the devDependencies alone. :(

Comment: as today - npm WARN install Usage of the `--dev` option is deprecated. Use `--only=dev` instead.

Comment: The latest version of NPM (v7) supports `--production=false` instead of the above.

Comment: `--production=false` does not solve the OP question: it installs dependencies and devDependencies, not ONLY devDependencies.

Answer (score 202, accepted):

Check the [NPM docs for install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install):

> With the `--production` flag (or when the `NODE_ENV` environment variable is set to production), npm will not install modules listed in `devDependencies`.
>
> The `--only={prod[uction]|dev[elopment]}` argument will cause either only devDependencies or only non-devDependencies to be installed regardless of the NODE_ENV.

Have you tried the following?

```
npm install --only=dev
```

Comment: Just now I found out that my npm version was 2.x . I upgraded it to v3.x by running the command `npm install npm -g` and **--only=dev** option worked like a charm. Thanks for the response.

Comment: The version issue mentioned by @NesanJoseph was the problem in my case too. In the older version of npm, `npm install --prod` used to install items from `dependencies` folder. Both `npm install` and `npm install --dev` used to install from *both* the `dependencies` and `devDependencies` folders!

Comment: I'm getting the same issue @ricka mentions using nvm to run node v 10.9.0 and npm v 6.4.1 (both latest versions as of 10/18) and also using --only=dev is still installing app dependencies as well. Basically npm install flags are 100% useless at this point.

Comment: Not working for me (node v12.19.0, npm v6.14.8). Perhaps it has something to do with this issue open since April 2016: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12184

Comment: It is wort noting that `--only=dev` is deprecated and will no longer work. I do not believe there is currently a way to install only the dev dependencies.

Comment: @MichaelMurphy UPVOTE HIM ! After npm 8, there is no way to only install devDependencies

Comment: I'm here because none of the long options worked after switching to npm 9, but `-D` does still work, and it does so without complaint. It appears the `-D` is now the *only* way.

Answer (score 84):

```
npm i -D
```

An optional short version.

Comment: YES, I had done `npm install -D` and it worked. so I was surprised and googled this, after many answer I see your answer :)

Comment: The command "npm install -D"  did not work for me, the node_modules is the same size as when i run "npm i"

Comment: I am not certain that `npm i -D` is doing what you expect. I can't see any reference to this in the documentation. I am assuming that the -D flag is being ignored and a normal `npm i` is being performed here. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install

Comment: As of npm 9, it appears this is no longer *optional*. It seems `-D` is now the *only* way.

Answer (score 45):

```
npm install thePackageName --save-dev
```

This works fine for me.

Comment: `--save-dev` saves the package to the devDependencies in package.json

Comment: --save-dev is meant to flag that the installed package would be installed under the devDependencies

Comment: More like `npm install thePackageName --save-dev`

Comment: This will install a single package explicit name and save it to dev dependencies. The question is about how to install only devDependencies from the package.json.

Comment: Doesn't meet the criteria for the question. Your answer is to install: 1. a single package 2. the question asks how to install stuff that's already in the package.json but only in the dependencies list.

Comment: Worked for me too!

Comment: this is the answer.

Comment: @notAChance while it may be the answer to your question, it is NOT the answer to the original question.

Comment: Here is the v8 documentation: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install

Comment: this one shall be the accepted answer for 2022.

Answer (score 21):

As of npm version 7.10.0 you can omit certain types of dependencies, however you cannot omit "the" dependencies (production) anymore. That's why there is no solution for this problem anymore.

Comment: I wonder why that line was arbitrarily drawn. Dependencies are bulky and with things running in containers now, it's often unnecessary to have all the dependencies installed for development.

Answer (score 10):

The --only=dev option is no longer supported.  To do the dev dependency install run `npm install --production=false`

Comment: Correct: --onyl=dev has been removed.
Wrong: --production=false is not a replacement for the initial question: install ONLY devDependencies (= do NOT install dependencies)

Comment: `npm install --production=false` will install all dependencies including normal and dev as this is what you would want when not in production (when you are in development).

Answer (score 5):

In the latest version of npm there is no way to install just the dev dependencies. But there is a workaround which you can do.

You can create another package_dev.json file where you can put only devDependencies and keep the dependencies empty.

Than to install just the dev dependencies you can execute the below script

```
cp package.json temp.json && \
cp package_dev.json package.json && \
npm install && \
rm -rf package.json && \
cp temp.json package.json && \
rm -rf temp.json
```

I've got the similar requirement where I need to create a gitHub action and just wanted to install dev dependencies. The above workaround worked like charm for me.

The only Con of the approach is that you need to take care of updating the package_dev.json every time when there is an update in package.json file.

Comment: This should be the answer for today

Answer (score 3):

Running `npm install`, It will install all dependencies under **devDependencies**` or **dependencies**.

For installing and save packages as dev dependencies in package.json, 
`npm install package_name --save-dev` or pass option `-D`

For installing all packages under **devDependencies**,
`npm install --only=dev`

For installing and save packages as prod or only dependencies in package.json, 
`npm install package_name --save-prod` or pass option `-P` or `npm install package_name`

For installing all packages under **dependencies** or **Prod dependencies**,
set Environment variable `NODE_ENV=production` or pass it with the command   `NODE_ENV=production npm install` or `npm install --only=prod`

Instead of using `install` in npm command like `npm install` you can just use `i` like `npm i`, short of install.

[Reference](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

Comment: This does not answer the OP question: "install ONLY the "devDependencies" listed in my package.json file"