# Install only devDependencies for NodeJS

Tags: docker, npm

I am using npm version 7.18.1. From what I see from the documentation the `--only=development` option no longer exists.

I'm creating a multi-stage Docker image. What I need to do is to create an image for the development step in which only `devDependency` packages are installed. On the next step, I'm going to create another image with production packages installed in it.

How do I do this without the --only=development option?

Comment: Have you tried `npm i -D` ? Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55525280/7011897

Comment: What a deeply buried solution. Thanks @PancakeAlchemist